Restriction in Sobolev embedding
I have the following doubt.
Proposition. Let $1<p<\infty$. If $sp<n$, then $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subset L^{{np}/{(n-sp)}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.
Reference: Proposition 6.4 in  M.E. Taylor, Partial Differential Equations III: Nonlinear Equations (Springer New York, New York, NY, 2011).
Question. Is the inclusion also valid on a "small set"?, i.e, if $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Is $H^{s,p}(\Omega)\subset L^{{np}/{(n-sp)}}(\Omega)$ also valid?
My attempt: Let $u\in H^{s,p}(\Omega)$, then, the extension $\tilde{u}$ defined by $\tilde{u}=u$ on $\Omega$ and $\tilde{u}=0$ on $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus\Omega$ belong to the space $H^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, so, by the proposition, $\tilde{u}\in L^{{np}/{(n-sp)}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Now, this implies that $u\in L^{{np}/{(n-sp)}}(\Omega)$. Is this correct?
Thanks.
